# unable to publish UWP through WPF with XamlIslands : Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets not found

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Good afternoon,

After [following rigourously this XamlIslands tutorial from WDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands), I've successfull been able to compile a test application thanks to .Net Core 3.0 ; the result you can see here

[image]

is the proof the tutorial is right : my application executes and runs fine in Debug mode.

Because I hope to deploy portable projects using UWP thanks to this technique, I tried to publish a .exe standalone file [using this tutorial.](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/) The tutorial works for a .net Core 3 project, as long as I don't try to publish my cross-technology project.

When I try to publish the XamlIslands project, here is what the console says :

```
PS C:\Users\████████████\source\repos\TestCore> dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea pour .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\████████████\source\repos\TestCore\MyUWPClass\MyUWPClass.csproj : warning NU1503: Ignorer la restauration du projet 'C:\Users\████████████\source\repos\TestCore\MyUWPClass\MyUWPClass.csproj'. Il est possible que le fichier projet ne soit pas valide ou qu'il ne contienne pas toutes les cibles nécessaires à la restauration. [C:\Users\████████████\source\repos\TestCore\TestCore.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\NuGet.targets(123,5): warning : Projet à restaurer introuvable ! [C:\Users\████████████\source\repos\TestCore\TestCore.sln]
C:\Users\████████████\source\repos\TestCore\MyUWPClass\MyUWPClass.csproj(143,3): error MSB4019: Le projet importé "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" est introuvable. Vérifiez que le chemin d'accès dans la déclaration <Import> est correct et que le fichier existe sur le disque.
```

I've verified on the folder and the missing file, obviously, doesn't exist. In fact, the folder "...\WindowsXaml" doesn't even exist.

Q : Am I able to publish such a project, and if yes, which package am I missing ?

Side notes :

- I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise Preview on Windows 10 v1903;
- VS2019 Preview seems to disable publishing : clicking on "Generate => Publish TestCore" doesn't even open a window.
- tried to install the .net Core 3 SDK : didn't helped;
- tried to install the NuGet package Microsoft.NetCore.targets : didn't helped;
- (EDIT)  After building a trivial WPF application (Window + "Hello" label inside), `right-click > Publish` doesn't show anything but using the console command `dotnet publish -r -win-x64 -c Release` gave me a publish folder and a standalone application. Also tried to package on a single .exe file and it worked too.

---

I've figured out that if you have installed .Net Core 3.0 SDK/Runtime, and if you copy the folder `your_project_folder/bin/x64/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/`, you will be able to run `your_project.exe` without publishing. It doesn't solve the publishing issue I had though, so the question stays opened.

Answer (score 0):

The packaged documentation you provide is for the ConsoleApp. There is currently no documentation for the dotnet-CLI package WPF program.

When you publish a WPF program in Visual Studio, it will not pop up, but please pay attention to the contents of the "`output`" window, it will post package in `your_project_folder/bin/x64/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/publish`, where you can Find published apps and their dependencies.

Best regards.

Comment: Hello,

I tried to watch the contents of the output window, unfortunately I had no more information than "Package manager" or "Build" can provide. I checked the `...\publish` folder too and it hasn't popped up.

For now, I've found out that if the .Net Core 3 Runtime or SDK is installed on the client computer, if we copy the `netcoreapp3.0` folder and run `my_project.exe` within, it works. I still have a publish issue, maybe not related to this particular case, but it will do the trick for the moment.

Thank you for the advice !

Comment: I am glad that you have found a solution. Although it is a temporary solution, there should be a better solution after the follow-up documentation is improved.